# Cannot create Azure Service Container

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I tried to create an Azure Service Container in the UK West region. I went through all the steps without issue however once I clicked 'Create' after a few moments I was met with :

> LocationNotAvailableForResourceTypeThe provided location 'ukwest' is not available for resource type 'Microsoft.ContainerService/containerServices'. List of available regions for the resource type is 'japaneast,centralus,eastus2,japanwest,eastasia,southcentralus,australiaeast,australiasoutheast,brazilsouth,southeastasia,westus,northcentralus,westeurope,northeurope,eastus'.

Okay, I realised that was my mistake and went on to create the container in West Europe.

Now when I attempt to create the container I am met with the same error, despite setting the location to West Europe.

I have tried :

1. Hard refreshing and going through the whole process again.
2. Clearing my web cache and going through the whole process again.
3. Opening an incognito window and going through the whole process
   again.

I have also ensured that the Azure Container Service and Azure Container Registry are registered on my subscription ID. Initially the resource group I was attempting to deploy on was set to UK West, however after deleting and recreating on West Europe, I still am unable to create the service container.

**Update:**

I have had Microsoft Azure Support on this case. It looks like there is an issue whereby my subscription ID cannot create the service container in the West Europe region. This has been referred onto the technical team. I'll post the solution here when I receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I've had MSFT Support on this with me for a couple weeks. The solution!

I had a dns that you couldn't use. Even though it passes through all validation checks telling me that it's fine the deployment failed.

Changed the dns and it's fine.

So to summarise all the things you need to do, which it doesn't state anywhere:

- Make sure you have registered Azure Container Service and Azure Container Registry on your subscription ID.
- Make sure you are deploying to a region that actually supports your feature, not only that make sure your resource group is located in the same valid region. (It allows you to pass through all validation selecting a resource group that is in an invalid region)
- Make sure your resource group hasn't been created by a previous failed deployment.
- Attempt to change your dns to something else, it might be invalid somehow. Although it will not tell you this, just fail the deployment.
- Essentially do not trust the validation on Azure at all. It'll tell you you're able to do things and everything is fine, when in fact it isn't.

I'll edit this answer with any further relevant update I receive.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Container Service is supported in westeurope region, you can see the support of the services in this link:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/

You clearly are not showing how you are creating your cluster, we need more info on the steps you are following and some screenshots. But just so you know,  **it actually works**, I just deployed a kubernetes cluster to the 'westeurope' region with the following commands on the [Az cli 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli):

```bash
RG=stackoverflowtest
LOCATION=westeurope
az group create --name=$RG --location=$LOCATION
az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes --resource-group $RG --name=$CLUSTER_NAME --dns-prefix=$DNS_PREFIX
```

This is the result you get after 5-10 minutes is something like this:

```
creating service principal.........done
waiting for AAD role to propagate.done
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxd/resourceGroups/stackoverflowtest/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/azureclixx.xx",
  "name": "azureclixx.xx",
  "properties": {
    "correlationId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "debugSetting": null,
    "dependencies": [],
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "outputs": null,
    "parameters": {
      "clientSecret": {
        "type": "SecureString"
      }
    },
    "parametersLink": null,
    "providers": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "namespace": "Microsoft.ContainerService",
        "registrationState": null,
        "resourceTypes": [
          {
            "aliases": null,
            "apiVersions": null,
            "locations": [
              "westeurope"
            ],
            "properties": null,
            "resourceType": "containerServices"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "template": null,
    "templateLink": null,
    "timestamp": "2017-03-14T21:00:39.066034+00:00"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "stackoverflowtest"
}
```

And, this is the official documentation on how to deploy a kubernetes ACS:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-kubernetes-walkthrough

Comment: I should have edited this really, I have a tech support ticket ongoing as doing it incorrect the first time seems to have ruined my subscription. Will update ticket when I know more. But thanks for confirming this does work! :)

Comment: Just remove the Resource Group you created and start again. You shouldn't have any problem, also if my answer was helpful I would appreciate if you can mark it as the right answer, but if it doesn't solve your predicament, give me more info and I will gladly help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Even though it passes through all validation checks telling me that it's fine the deployment failed. 
   Changed the dns and it's fine.*

This should not happen now as ACS has started surfacing more detailed error messages. Also, ACS has another change rolling out currently regarding DNS name already taken error and should be available world wide in ~2 weeks. With this change the error message should be more detailed and actionable.

2. *Make sure you have registered Azure Container Service and Azure Container Registry on your subscription ID.*

User does not need to register for ACR in order to use ACS unless their scenario needs it.

3. *Make sure you are deploying to a region that actually supports your feature, not only that make sure your resource group is located in the same valid region. (It allows you to pass through all validation selecting a resource group that is in an invalid region)*

I am assuming you deployed using portal. At one point portal was showing all public Azure regions and not just ACS regions. This has since been fixed.

4. *Make sure your resource group hasn't been created by a previous failed deployment.*

This is by design (ACS will be created in the region that the resource group is in even if resource group name is unique globally).

5. *Attempt to change your dns to something else, it might be invalid somehow. Although it will not tell you this, just fail the deployment.*

An already created ACS resource does not allow user to change the DNS name prefix. If you don't mind sharing an operation id/resource name I can look into this and get back to you.